# Open SSL Support disabled

Tags: php, laravel, apache

I just installed apache and php with guide of this youtube video :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kuMTZowwjus

server runs and loads files in htdocs but when I create file with phpInfo() in it in htdocs
I have problem with this :

OpenSSL support     disabled (install ext/openssl)

I'm trying to run laravel application with this , for this I installed composer then I used composer to download and install laravel files in htdocs , I could run laravel project but laravel throw and error which is related to Openssl 
this is the error :

Call to undefined function Illuminate\Encryption\openssl_cipher_iv_length()

Comment: It means a PHP extension (php.ini)

Answer (score 0):

Uncommente in php.ini file

```
;extension=php_openssl
```

to:

```
extension=ext/php_openssl
```

And restart your apache server

Comment: I have no line with code : extension=ext/php_openssl in php.ini in php folder , Instead I have extension=openssl

Comment: Something like this to remove !